# echo php string not working

Tags: php, echo

I have a php file with the following string:

```
<button type="button" <?php echo "onclick=\"window.location.href = '" . $page_config->generateHrefLinkParams('to_cta') . "&opt='+opt;\""; ?>>Continuar</button>
```

Where `$page_config->generateHrefLinkParams('to_cta')` gives me a URL like `whatever.com?var=var` (I use it in other files, it works).

So the result I'm expecting to see on the browser would be

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'whatever.com?var=var&opt='+opt;">Continuar</button>
```

However, I can't make it work, I don't get an error from the server, the code is just not parsed from that line on. I tried other solutions, variations on the escaped characters, other concatenation methods, nothing works.

What am I missing here?

Is there a more proper way to write this code?

Comment: What does it say in the Error logs?

Comment: Do you get any runtime errors in your browser?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me, if I just substitute a hardcoded `"whatever.com?var=var"` for the function call and supply an `opt` variable for the JS. Let's see your server error logs, and the output you get at the point of failure.

Comment: i feel like something with the quotes is a little off... what does it actually output?  or does it even output anything?  there's no javascript errors, right?

Comment: My guess is this `$page_config->generateHrefLinkParams('to_cta')` is not defined, try echoing only this var

Comment: there are no javascript errors, I get no runtime errors on my browser and my server doesn't throw me any errors at all (probably the way my IT department set it up). All that happens is the generated HTML ends before that line; I don't even see the "button" tag on the final markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct, there was some other configuration error in the server that the IT department fixed. Non related to the code itself.